# Is it possible to receive push notifications from WNS in a WPF app, which uses Xaml Islands?

Tags: wpf, uwp, wns, xaml-islands

I'm creating an app in WPF and using Xaml Islands to add UWP look and feel to it.

I'd like to receive push notifications from Amazon SNS, using the Windows Push Notification Services (WNS). Following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/request-create-save-notification-channel) article to create a notification channel, I tried to run the this code:

```
await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
```

But it failed with the following very verbose exception: `Element not found. (0x80070490)`. I tried also to run it in a custom UWP component, but the result was the same.

So, my question is that, is it possible to receive push notifications from WNS with this kind of app type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of investigation and searching, I found that the answer is: yes.
The very simple thing what should be done, is just to run the Desktop Bridge project inside the solution, not the `WPF` app, how I tried to do.